# How do I loop through children objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a function:

```
tableFields = tableFields.children;
for (item in tableFields) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

According to a console.log of tableFields, I am getting an array back as I assume I need to do. A console.log of item within the loops returns undefined. What do I have to do to loop through tableFields and insert each object into a table?

console log of tableFields:

```
HTMLCollection[label, input, label, input 25, label, input, input, input Remove]


0
label

1
input

2
label

3
input 25

4
label

5
input

6
input

7 
input Remove

description[]
input

hours[]
input

invoice_number
input

getlength
8

rate[]
input 25

item
item()

iterator
iterator()

namedItem
namedItem()

__proto__
HTMLCollectionPrototype { item=item(), namedItem=namedItem(), iterator=iterator()}
```

Here is the entire section of code as I have so far:

```
$this->title("Test");
    $this->defaultMenu();
    $select = "";
    $names = Customer::getNames();
    foreach ($names as $id => $name) {
        $select .= '<option value="'.$id.'"';
        if ($this->customerid == $id) $select .= ' selected ';
        $select .= '>'.$name.'</option>';
    }

    $form = '
<script type="text/javascript">

var counter = 0;

function isEven(int){
int = Number(int);
return (int%2 == 0);
}



function moreLabor() {

    var table = document.getElementById("editTable");
    var tableFields = document.getElementById("readroot");

    tableFields = tableFields.children;
    console.log(tableFields);
    for (item in tableFields) {

        if (isEven(counter)) {
            var tableRow = table.insertRow(-1);
            var label = tableRow.insertCell(-1);
            console.log(tableFields[item]);
            label.appendChild(tableFields[item]);

        } else {
            var field = tableRow.insertCell(-1);
            field.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;


        }

        counter++;
    }

    console.log();
var insertHere = document.getElementById("writeroot");
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById(\'moreLabor\').onclick = function(){ moreLabor(); }
    moreLabor();
}


</script>

<div id="readroot" style="display: none">
<tr>
    <td><label for="hours">Hours:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="hours[]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="rate">Rate:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" value="25" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="description">Description:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" value="" /></td>
</tr>

<input type="hidden" name="invoice_number" value="'.$this->number.'" />
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Remove"
    onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /></td>
</tr>

</div>

<form method="POST" class="invoice" id="edit">
<table id="editTable">
    <tr>
        <td><label>Work Order Number:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="number" value="'.$this->number.'"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Customer:</label></td>
        <td><select name="customerid">'.$select.'</select></td>
    </tr>
    <span id="writeroot"></span>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="moreLabor" value="Add labor"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>';
    if (!is_null($this->id)) {
        $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$this->id.'"/>';
    }
    $form .= '</table></form>';



    $this->component($form);
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The trick is that [the DOM `Element.children` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children) is not an array but an *array-like collection* which has length and can be indexed like an array, but it is not an array:

```javascript
var children = tableFields.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var tableChild = children[i];
  // Do stuff
}
```

Incidentally, in general it is a better practice to iterate over an array using a basic for-loop instead of a for-in-loop.

Comment: so how do I get the inner elements of a parent element?

Comment: @CoreyRay: in my sample code "tableFields" is the parent element and "children" are the child elements.

Comment: I found this to work fine: `for(let x of Array.from(tableFields.children)) {...}`

Comment: This only looks at the direct children of tableFields; you want to use getElementsByTagName('*') to see all children and nested-children. See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/gd3eokb5/5/

Comment: Replying to an old topic, but thanks, I was just running into this issue. This 'array-like collection', what's the rationale behind that, rather than just using an array?

Comment: @RocketNuts an HTMLCollection offers additional methods for handling html elements so it's more useful than an array. As noted above you can iterate through the items using for (ele of collection) ...

Comment: Why is a basic for-loop better than a for-in-loop?

Comment: This is still in top 5 dumbest things JS ever did. Why would you make an 'array-like collection' that works mostly like an array but still isn't? I'm sure there was a reason at some point but it's just such a bad design.

Answer (score 55):

In **ECS6**, one may use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [Spread array syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals):

```
const listItems = document.querySelector('ul').children;
const listArray = Array.from(listItems);
// or
const listArray = [...listItems];
listArray.forEach((item) => {console.log(item)});
```

Comment: Strangely this method is much faster (about 15x in Chrome) than itering directly the `children` property like the first answer suggests. Wonder why...

Comment: How did you test that "15x" performance improvement? I would assume that `Array.from() ` would perform better with tracing JIT compiler when the same code is executed thousands or millions of times in a loop. However, for a single loop, I would expect directly iterating through `.children` being faster.

Answer (score 13):

Modern JS also uses the *[for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)* to enable us to iterate DOM children objects, array, or other iterable objects. I think it is very clean and simple.

```
var children = tableFields.children;
for (c of children) { 
  console.log(c);
  // Do stuff with child c
}
```

Answer (score 7):

if `tableFields` is an array , you can loop through elements as  following :

```
for (item in tableFields); {
     console.log(tableFields[item]);
}
```

by the way i saw a logical error in you'r code.just remove `;` from end of for loop

right here  :

`for (item in tableFields); {` .

this will cause you'r loop to do just nothing.and the following line will be executed only once :

```
// Do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the suggested changes. I am trying to appendChild these items to a table row object

Answer (score 6):

The backwards compatible version (IE9+) is

```
var parent = document.querySelector(selector);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.children, function(child, index){
  // Do stuff
});
```

The es6 way is

```
const parent = document.querySelector(selector);
Array.from(parent.children).forEach((child, index) => {
  // Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using ES6,

```js
[...element.children].map(child => console.log(child));
```

Answer (score 3):

In the year 2020 / 2021 it is even easier with `Array.from` to 'convert' from a array-like nodes to an actual array, and then using `.map` to loop through the resulting array.
The code is as simple as the follows:

```
Array.from(tableFields.children).map((child)=>console.log(child))
```

Comment: Quick, time saving and the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

I’m surprised no-one answered with this code:

```
for(var child=elt.firstChild;
    child;
    child=child.nextSibling){
  do_thing(child);
}
```

Or, if you only want children which are elements,
this code:

```
for(var child=elt.firstElementChild;
    child;
    child=child.nextElementSibling){
  do_thing(child);
}
```