# Displaying countdown in a table using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have attempted using the for loop to display my Countdown, but I don't know where I am getting it wrong. Is there a simpler way to display the countdown for each row using vanilla javascript?

My Table Below:

```
<html>
<body> 
<table style="width:50%" id= "tab">
    <tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Exp</th>
<th>Count Down</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
     <td> A</td>
     <td class = 'exp1'> 09/08/2019</td>
     <td class = 'demo'> </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> B</td>
     <td class = 'exp1'> 09/08/2020</td>
     <td class = 'demo'> </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
<script>
var exp = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('exp1');

var x = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('demo');

var   now = new Date();
function test(){

for (i = 0; i<exp.length; i++){
var  e = new Date( exp[i].innerHTML);
var  timeDiff = e.getTime() - now.getTime();
var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var hours   = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
var days    = Math.floor(hours   / 24);
hours %=24;
minutes %=60;
seconds %=60;
var timer = setTimeout('test()', 1000);   
}

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
x[i].innerHTML = days  + " " +  hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through children objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094230/how-do-i-loop-through-children-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should give your  a class property instead of an id as there should be only one element with the same id.

Second, you can get all elements with

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('demo')
```

Third, you can then do

```
var c;
for (c = 0; c < elements.length; c++) {
// calculate and change the value here
// for each elements[c]
}
```

For further explanation see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

---

Edit as answer to comment:

You can call the function every second with

```
window.setInterval(function(){
/// call your function here
}, 1000);
```

See [What's the easiest way to call a function every 5 seconds in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery)

On how to calculate the time from the timediff see [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

To change the value inside of the  you add the following inside your for loop

```
document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[c].innerHTML = newstring
```

as already answered here: [Setting innerHTML: Why won't it update the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196240/setting-innerhtml-why-wont-it-update-the-dom)

Comment: I don't have problem accessing the elements using class name, my problem is  it to display countdown for each row.