# How i can iterate over nested section elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi I have the next strucutre in a web:

```
<section class="item-list clearfix jq-itemList">

  <section id="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="1111" style="height: 562px;">
</section>

  <section id="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="2222" style="height: 562px;">
</section>

  <section id="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="3333" style="height: 562px;">
</section>

 </section>
```

How I can iterate over the nested sections inside the parent section with pure javascript?

I tried with something like:

```
document.getElementById("section").getElementsByTagName("section");
```

but is not working, what is the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you have duplicate IDs, which is invalid markup. IDs must be unique. Use classes instead. Also, your selector is invalid; there's no `section` ID.

Comment: There's no `id="section"` anywhere.

Comment: @ObsidianAge He's not selecting the duplicate ID, so it shouldn't affect the results.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I loop through children objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17094230/215552)

Comment: Do you have anything to identify that parent `section` besides the classes? Are there other `section`s in your document? Do you want just those three child `section`s or do you also want any descendant `section`s that may exist?

Answer (score 3):

Use [queryselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and use css selector `section section` :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('section section').forEach(e => {
  const id = e.getAttribute('data');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<section class="item-list clearfix jq-itemList">

  <section id="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="1111" style="height: 562px;">
  </section>

  <section id="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="2222" style="height: 562px;">
  </section>

  <section id="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="3333" style="height: 562px;">
  </section>

</section>
```

Keep in mind that `id` should be unique to the element, you might want to consider changing the `id`s of the sections.

Answer (score 0):

Using non unique `id` is [illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454716/860099) and will cause many problems. Use `name` attribute instead with querySelector

```
sections= document.querySelectorAll('section section[name=cart-section]');

sections.forEach(s=> console.log(s.getAttribute('data')) );
```

```js
sections = document.querySelectorAll('section section[name=cart-section]');

sections.forEach(s => console.log(s.getAttribute('data')));
```

```html
<section class="item-list clearfix jq-itemList">

  <section name="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="1111" style="height: 562px;">
  </section>

  <section name="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="2222" style="height: 562px;">
  </section>

  <section name="cart-section" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 item" displaynamemaxlength="50" data="3333" style="height: 562px;">
  </section>

</section>
```