# Getting Uncaught TypeError in for each it said its not a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, foreach

My html

```
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid" id="grid-div">
        <div class="cell1"></div>
        <div class="cell2"></div>
        <div class="cell3"></div>
        <div class="cell4"></div>
        <div class="cell5"></div>
        <div class="cell6"></div>
        <div class="cell7"></div>
        <div class="cell8"></div>
        <div class="cell9"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my js

```
    const grid = document.getElementById("grid-div");
    console.log(grid.children[3]);

    let gridArr = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    let X = true;

    let gridcell = grid.children;
    gridcell.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", (cell.textContent = "X"));
});
```

its returning an **error** which is

```
index.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: grid.children.forEach is not a function
    at index.js:7:15
```

whats wrong here?

I would like to add event listener in all the children of the grid div

```
    <div class="grid" id="grid-div">
        <div class="cell1"></div>
        <div class="cell2"></div>
        <div class="cell3"></div>
        <div class="cell4"></div>
        <div class="cell5"></div>
        <div class="cell6"></div>
        <div class="cell7"></div>
        <div class="cell8"></div>
        <div class="cell9"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid.children` is actually a `HTMLCollection` type. The problem with your code is that you are iterating through children as if it is an `array` type.

Thus, you need to use a different approach to iterate over the children nodes. There are many ways to approach this such as with [this solution using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094318/9851824), or if you want a cleaner approach [this solution using a for of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67632405/9851824) works too.

Essentially, your code can look something like the following:

```js
for (const cell of gridcell) {
  cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
    cell.textContent = 'X';
  });
}
```

As a side note, `addEventListener`'s second argument expects a callback. So you probably want to pass a function or an anonymous function like I show above.

Comment: Thanks, Its my first time knowing HTMLCollection type I thought it was just an array

Answer (score 0):

`grid.children` is an object, not array.

If you wanted to use forEach on object, then you need to do it in a different way as object consists of key-values.

```js
const grid = document.getElementById("grid-div");
let gridcell = grid.children;

console.log(typeof gridcell); // You can see here, it's an object not array.

//Way to iterate an object with forEach
Object.keys(gridcell).forEach(itr => {
  gridcell[itr].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    gridcell[itr].textContent = "X";
  });
});
```

```css
#grid-div>div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid" id="grid-div">
        <div class="cell1"></div>
        <div class="cell2"></div>
        <div class="cell3"></div>
        <div class="cell4"></div>
        <div class="cell5"></div>
        <div class="cell6"></div>
        <div class="cell7"></div>
        <div class="cell8"></div>
        <div class="cell9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```